# Box2d world width and height ratio with screen width and height

Tags: android, jbox2d

I have view, for example **GameView** which extends **SurfaceView** . I have integrated Box2D physics in GameView. I have two widths ,

GameView width, height and Box2D physics world width ,height. I need to get the position of box2d world with the GameView co-ordinates.

For example,

Total width of screen = 240
Total height of screen = 320

Screen points needed to be mapped onto box2d co-ordinates (x,y) = 127, 139

For this i need to get the max width and height of the Box2d physics world. Is there is any way to get the max width and height of Box2d world.

or

Can i limit the width and height of box2d world within the screen resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to mix your data object with your visual objects. For the purpose of this issue, this is a big no-no.

Your screen is a visual object, and your sprites/models/etc are visual objects. Those will matter. Box2D on the other hand is not a visual object, so there is no magical direct mapping.

You could decide that arbitrarily the top-left corner of the screen maps to 0,0 in Box2d, and that every 10 pixels is equivelant to 1 unit in Box2D. For your data model that would work just fine.

The real question here is how does your Box2D units match your visual units. If you have a 64x64 2d sprite that happens to be a box. How big is your box2d square? Is it 1 unit, 10 units, or 64 units?

Answer (score 0):

You need a transform from your screen to world coordinates.  This is usually accomplished with a 'scale' factor and a positional offset.  For the testbed I use a Mat22 (which means I can do rotation), a center position, and the screen size measurements:

https://github.com/dmurph/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/common/OBBViewportTransform.java